# Creating deck of cards in C

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to create a deck of cards in C. The way I want to implement this is by having a 2 dimensional array of `deck[51][1]`, which will have 52 slots of 2 slots each. The first slot will contain the card value (1-52) and the second slot will contain the suit (1-4).

I have tried to assign this by using the below code:

```
int deck[51][1];
int i;
int j;
int suit = 1;

int main()
{
    for(i=0; i<52; i++){
        for(j=0; j<2; j++){
            if(j==0){
                deck[i][j] = i+1;
            } else {
                deck[i][j] = suit % 4;
            }
            suit++;
        }
    }
```

I then try and make it print out every card's value using the following double loop:

```
for(i=0; i<52; i++){
    for(j=0; j<2; j++){
        printf("%i ",deck[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

return 0;
```

}

However instead of resulting in 52 lines of the card value followed by its suit, it just displays a weird

```
1 2
2 3
3 4
4 5
5 6
6 7
7 8
8 9
```

and so on until

```
51 52
52 0
```

I can't work out why it's not assigning the `suit % 4` value to the second item of every array, which should result in a neat

```
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 4
5 1
6 2
7 3
8 4
```

Comment: `deck[51][1]` means 51*1, you want `deck[52][2]`

Comment: not directly related, but why have a separate field for four suits when you have 52 card values already? Did you want something like deck[13][4]?

Comment: Because I want to be able to shuffle the deck afterwards, also I want to be able to shrink the deck afterwards depending on what cards had already been taken from the deck.

Comment: The 2-d array is silly. Just have each card be a single number, and derive the rank and suit from that--simpler, faster. That's what I do in http://lcrocker.github.io/onejoker/cardlib/ , for example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although array indexes in C are zero-based, it does not mean that the compiler would add `1` to each dimension on a declaration. Your declaration makes an array that is 51x1, not 52x2. For 52x2 array use

```
int deck[52][2];
```

Your current implementation has undefined behavior, which makes the output of your program incorrect: accessing `deck[x][1]` goes past the boundaries of the array, producing incorrect output.

Comment: God.. Ok thank you. My teacher did not explain this to me properly. I thought that indexing and array size declarations would work the same way. Thanks!

Comment: @Aron `if (age < 18) BlameTeacher =  true;  else BlameStudent =  true;`